# How to query a List<MyClass> with another list<int> into a new List<MyClass>

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists:

```
static List<Parts> partList = new List<Parts>();
```

The class it refers to:

```
class Parts
{
    int chassisNumber;

    public int ChassisNumber
    {
        get { return chassisNumber; }
        set { chassisNumber = value; }
    }

    int partsCount;

    public int PartsCount
    {
        get { return partsCount; }
        set { partsCount = value; }
    }
```

And the another one:

```
static List<int> shuffledChassisList = new List<int>();
```

shuffledChassisList contains a subset of chassis numbers loaded into List ChassisNumber.
I want to use shuffledChassisList to query the List into a new List, for ex: List filteredPartList.

I tried to use Linq but failed to write a working solution that would create a new list with filtered results.

Then, I want to use this filtered list to categorise parts into new lists depending on part number count (for ex: I want to copy all parts from List filteredPartList into List emptyPackageList where a Part's partsCount is 0).

So far I got this, but not sure what to write in the foreach loop:

```
static List<Parts> emptyPackageList = new List<Parts>();

var emptyPackage = filteredPartList.Where(p => p.partsCount == 0);

foreach (var part in emptyPackage)
{
    emptyPackageList.Add(new Parts(??));
}
```

If it is possible to write one method that does this two thing one it is fine for me.

**edit:**
The reason why I need to have two lists is because I query a database to get the chassis numbers and the parts count which belonging to it. I asked the community, but unfortunately it seems that it is not possible to make this query to run on selected chassis numbers. So I have the partscount for all the chassisnumbers (`List<Parts> partList`), which I need to filter with ones I am looking for (`List<int> shuffledChassisList`), then group by into new lists by partscount.

If it is possible or easier to filter the `List<Parts> partList` by the `List<int> shuffledChassisList` then group by the results by partsCount and then copy the Parts into several new lists, then it is also an acceptable solution.

Comment: It is not clear how the part of the two lists is connected to the given code snippet

Comment: shuffledChassisList contains chassisNumbers (but only the subset of what's in partList), which is also available in the Parts class. Check my comment on Bruno's answer to view why is it necessary to have two different lists. Thanks.

Comment: You should clarify it in question and not comments - so clear for future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class does not specify a constructor and thus has only the default constructor. To populate the new instance with data use the object initializer syntax:

```
var emptyPackage = filteredPartList.Where(p => p.partsCount == 0);
foreach (var part in emptyPackage)
{
    emptyPackageList.Add(new Parts { ChassisNumber = part.ChassisNumber, PartsCount = part.PartsCount } );
}
```

Also if already using linq then use `.Select` to project the new instances:

```
var emptyPackage = filteredPartList.Where(p => p.partsCount == 0)
                                   .Select(p => new Parts {
                                       ChassisNumber = part.ChassisNumber, 
                                       PartsCount = part.PartsCount 
                                   }).ToList();
```

Notice that this creates a deep-copy of your objects as you instantiate a new object and set its properties. If a shallow copy is enough then just:

```
var emptyPackage = filteredPartList.Where(p => p.partsCount == 0).ToList();
```

---

In addition consider the following:

1. As your properties' implementations are the default ones, use auto-properties:

   ```
   class Parts
   {
       public int ChassisNumber { get; set; }
       public int PartsCount { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Implement a copy constructor or the `IClonable` interface and then:

   ```
   //copy constructor
   filteredPartList.Where(p => p.partsCount == 0).Select(p => new Parts(p));
   //clone
   filteredPartList.Where(p => p.partsCount == 0).Select(p => p.Clone());
   ```

---

If I understood your update correctly then:

```
var result = filteredPartList.Where(p => p.partsCount == 0 && 
                                         shuffledChassisList.Contains(p.ChassisNumber))
                             .GroupBy(p => partsCount)
                             .ToList();
```

Also consider changing `shuffledChassisList` to be a `HashSet<int>` so `Contains` will be an `O(1)` operation instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this at home and let you know what I've got.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I did not get your proper intention but here is what you can do:

If you have a list of parts and want to categorize them by PartsCount:

```
var categorized = myList.GroupBy(p=>p.PartsCount, p=>p);
```

If you want to get all items from one list if id belonging to another:

```
var filtered = myList.Where(p=>idList.Contains(p.Id));
```

Maybe by combining both methods you can get what you want (which is still a bit unclear to me)

Comment: I query a database to get the chassis numbers and the parts count which belonging to it. I asked the community, but unfortunately it seems that it is not possible to make this query to run on selected chassis numbers. So I have the partscount for all the chassisnumbers, which I need to filter with ones I am looking for, then group by into new lists by partscount. That is why I wrote, that would be good to handle the filter and group by in method. How to create a new list from your second code, append ToList() to the end?

Comment: yes, just add .ToList() to transform it into a List

Comment: Thanks, I will try this at home and let you know what I've got.